# What is the purpose of Embeded code under share tab in GDB

Tags: debugging, hyperlink, gdb, gdb-python

In GDB online debugger, when I click on the "Share" tab,
1st option is: shareable link
2nd option is embedded code
What is the purpose of the embedded code?

Comment: It is an `embed code` not `embedded code`. It is for embedding  into your own site rather then a link that goes to their site. It is certainly not an [embedded] tag question, or any of the other tags you have added for that matter.  I am not even convinced that it is a question for SO.  You should include a link to the site your are referring to in any event, and possibly an example of an actual embed code generated.

Comment: well...you might be an expert in this field but I am a beginner. It was my assignment in which I had to discover each and every functionality of  "GDB" I couldn't understand what embed code is doing there. I even searched on this, then I posted a question. I appreciate you for giving an answer but keep in mind your words can hurt someone and can degrade them. so if you really think the question someone tasked is according to your standard then give answer otherwise leave it. Thanks

Comment: it has nothing to do with gdb, it is a feature of that website, which despite its name is not specifically gdb.  Rather it is an online IDE  incorporating both GCC and GDB.  Few if any other online compilers support debugging, so the name is to emphasise that fact.  But be clear the website allows access to GDB, but it is not only GDB.

Comment: I think you may be somewhat oversensitive. I have reread my comment, and I see nothing offensive. It was intended as comment to allow you to improve your engagement with SO.  I apologise for any offence, it was not intentional.  When you select  frequently used tag, when you hover over it, it shows a description of the tag.  You will see that [embedded] refers specifically  to _embedded systems_,.

Comment: BTW I an not an expert in this field at all, I am an embedded systems engineer, which is why your post attracted my attention, and why appropriate tagging is essential.

Comment: ohk...understood...by the way thank you